# Snowflake: Convert different unix time formats to datetime

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-format

Data is not always clean and correctly format. Consider the case of unix times.

Is there a way to handle all these cases with a single transformation into a snowflake datetime?

```
SELECT '1620205203.611'::
UNION ALL
SELECT '1620205203611'::
UNION ALL
SELECT '1.620205203611000e+09'::
```

expected datetime should be `2021-05-05 09:00:03.611`

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` could be used:

```
WITH cte(c) AS (
  SELECT '1620205203.611'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1620205203611'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.620205203611000e+09'
) 
SELECT cte.c,  
       DATEADD(SECOND, CASE WHEN cte.c > 1e+11 THEN cte.c/1000 ELSE cte.c END
               ,'1970-01-01'::DATE) AS result
FROM cte;
```

Output:

[image]